# How to convert a base64 png string to base64 svg string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there anyway we can directly convert datauri png string to datauri svg string?

Comment: Since svg is predominantly a vector/bézier curve based format whereas png/jpeg/webp etc. are pixel based – you can't convert pixel based data urls automatically to a vector data structure. You could actually embed an png data url in svg using a `<image>`  element. Please add some example code.

Answer (score 1):

This conversion would not be direct, because converting vector image to raster image needs **graphical process** based on the output image size.